# After upgrading to postgresql 13.8 getting error the server does not support SSL

Tags: postgresql

We have upgraded the postgresql version from 9.6 to 13.8 in our lab. Post upgrade and initialization our application is keep restarting due to the below error in the log

*Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'migration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'credentialedDataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (**The server does not support SSL**.)*

What does the above error mean? How to fix it? Do we need to do anything with the server.crt and server.key files? Meaning, reimport or regenerate.

Pls let me know if you need any other detail from me.

Just playing with the postgresql parameters in pg_hba.conf file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to carry the server.crt and server.key over from the old server to the new one (if you didn't already).  You also need to change "ssl" parameter in the new postgresql.conf file, since you apparently haven't done so.

You should carefully consider the differences between the old postgresql.conf and the new one to decide how the differences should be resolved. 9.6 to 13 is a pretty big jump, and some parameters are new, some are obsolete, and some have changed their defaults or their meanings (or spellings).

Comment: Thank you much for responding to my query. Appreciate it. 

Here is the update. I compared the content of postgresql.conf file and uncommented parameters like ssl=on and listen_addresses = '0.0.0.0'. Post modification I stopped the postgresql service and could not start. 

Here's what I tried 
# systemctl stop postgresql-13.service
# systemctl start postgresql-13.service
Job for postgresql-13.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status postgresql-13.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: You should look in the database server's log file to see why it didn't start.  In my experience systemctl and journalctl are not very useful very often.  If this is an Ubuntu-like system, the pg_lsclusters command you should tell you where to find the log file.

Comment: Thanks again @jjanes. Now the ssl does not support error has gone. This was due to file ownership of server.cert and server.key files were set to root instead of postgres. But I have got another issue

Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not open SSL root certificate file /root/.postgresql/root.crt.)

When checked the hidden directory and files under /root they were not exist. I am not sure who and when creates it. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like the client can't find its certs.  The client is presumably running as root, which is why it is looking in /root/.postgresql for them.  The client doesn't actually need this file unless it is told to verify the cert it gets from the server (e.g. PGSSLMODE is verify-ca or verify-full; but the exact details on that vary with the client)

Comment: That's right. We are using verify-full as the ssl mode and also the client is running as root. Now, what is the way to generate root.crt. With our previous postgresql 9.6 version we didn't have this file with the same settings and configuration which is confusing me.